# Is declaring variables as const redundant after constexpr was added to the language?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr

As the keyword `constexpr` implies `const` and it can also be calculated at compile time, does it mean that now declaring variables as `const` doesn't make sense and we should always declare them as `constexpr`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> and it can also be calculated at compile time, does it mean that now declaring variables as `const` doesn't make sense and we should always declare them as `constexpr`?

And *must* be calculated at compile time (ignoring the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)).

So you can't declare `constexpr` a variable initialized with a run-time known value. But you can declare it `const`.

For example: you can't declare `bar` `constexpr`

```
int foo;

std::cin >> foo;

constexpr int bar = foo;  // compilation error
```

but you can declare it `const`

```
int foo;

std::cin >> foo;

const int bar = foo;  // compile
```

Comment: And must be calculated compile time. - I think it's still _can_, as in the end compiler decided on it's own and noone gives 100% guarantee that all constexpr expressions will be evaluated at a compile time

Comment: @Johy - You're describing the as-if rule. Yes: the compiler can compute the value for a `constexpr` variable also run-time, if this doesn't change the behavior of the program. Added a little disclaimer in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

No, not at all.

`constexpr` means "constant expression", as in [possibly] statically-known, as in "[possibly] known at compile time".

`const` means "cannot be changed after initialisation".

These are completely separate concepts. A `const` object can be initialised with a runtime value, for example.

`constexpr` can *imply* `const`, but `const` certainly does not imply `constexpr`.

*(I think `constexpr` is a very confusing name, due to this.)*

Comment: *"but const certainly does not imply constexpr"* - except for the annoying little legacy tidbit involving integral types and enumerations. Where it may be a bit of a Schrödinger's constexpr.

Comment: constexpr can imply const - you mean that there are cases when constexpr variables can be reassigned with another value? I though that constexpr vars always const

Comment: @Johy I mean that a `constexpr` thing can be (and usually/always is?) "immutable", which is what `const` means.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @max66 answer: `constexpr` can only replace a *top-level* `const`. It can never replace pointer-to-const or const reference. So, sometimes `constexpr` and `const` can be used in the same declaration. E.g.

```
const char* const s = "Hello";
```

can be replaced with:

```
constexpr const char* s = "Hello";
```

Comment: Now consider `const char* const s = getValueFromSomewhere();`